# DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know, I know the problem has been has been solved except, it hasn't.

I'm running:

mongoose 5.8.4 and nodemon 2.0.2 in case it's relevant.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
      // useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected!'))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.msg);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

When I run the server with `useUnifiedTopology: true` after 30 or so seconds a msg shows up saying:

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Any ideas on how to fix this bug?

Comment: If you don't use `useUnifiedTopology` and wait the same amount of time, does the app not crash?

Comment: It does, or, did.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new cluster on Atlas and everything works fine. Thanks anyways, guys.